Как JS кодом сделать динамичекое обновление рандомных значений?
Делаю простенькую браузерную игру, нужно чтобы в окне счетчика значение незначительно прыгало.
Например берем из базы переменную $power = 1.34, $power1 = 1.32, $power3 = 1.30
Нужно чтобы эти три значения выводились в случайном порядке и значение изменялось к примеру каждую секунду (т. е. имитация нестабильной подачи энергии). При чем скрипт должен выполняться сразу после перехода на страницу без вызова функции через onclick или post, get.

Забыл дополнить, код должен выполняться постоянно, т.е должен быть зацикленным, не должен останавливаться,

Все перерыл, ничего подобного не нашел — Это же цепочка маленьких задач, попробуйте писать самостоятельно. Что не получается?

При открытии страницы(onload) post запросом выдергиваете значения, кладете их в массив, пускаете setInterval в котором Math.random выдергиваете случайный элемент из массива и помещаете в нужное место на странице

все конечно может быть и просто, но в js я полный ноль, только начал изучать, весь скрипт игры почти на полном php, мне бы пример кода абы какой


Например берем из базы переменную $power = 1.34, $power1 = 1.32, $power3 = 1.30 Нужно чтобы эти три значения выводились в случайном порядке и значение изменялось к примеру каждую секунду (т. е. имитация нестабильной подачи энергии). При чем скрипт должен выполняться сразу после перехода на страницу без вызова функции через onclick или post, get.

Вот небольшой набросок, как такое можно реализовать...


const power = [1.34, 1.32, 1.30]
test()
setInterval(test, 1000)
//
function test() {
  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * power.length)
  document.querySelector('span').textContent = power[i]
}
<p>Энергия <span></span></p>




Дак это не набросок, это мне и нужно было, спасибо огромное!
